# METODO CONTAR EN PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, booleano, count

Mi problema a resolver trata de un DataFrame de la lista de descargas de modelos, como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cual tengo que crear un DataFrame resultado que obtenga por cada modelo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello he hecho este código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calcular_estadisticas(descargas:pd.DataFrame)->pd.DataFrame:
    # Paso 1: cargar los datos
    df = pd.DataFrame(descargas)
    
    # Paso 2: filtrar los datos
    df_pagados = df[df["PAGO"] > 0]
    
    # Paso 3: calcular las estadísticas
    agg_dict = {
        "PAGO": ["count", "mean", "max", "min"],
        "ESTRELLAS": ["mean", "std"],
        "COMENTARIO": ["count"]
    }
    stats = df_pagados.groupby("MODELO").agg(agg_dict)
    
    # Paso 4: crear el DataFrame resultado
    resultado = pd.DataFrame({
        "CANTIDAD": stats["PAGO"]["count"].astype(int),
        "PROMEDIO": stats["PAGO"]["mean"].round(2),
        "MAXIMO": stats["PAGO"]["max"].round(2),
        "MINIMO": stats["PAGO"]["min"].round(2),
        "ESTRELLAS": stats["ESTRELLAS"]["mean"].round(2),
        "DESV. ESTRELLAS": stats["ESTRELLAS"]["std"].fillna(0).round(2),
        "COMENTARIOS": stats["COMENTARIO"]["count"].astype(int)
    }, index=stats.index)
    
    # Ordenar los resultados alfabéticamente por nombre de modelo
    resultado = resultado.sort_index()
    
    return resultado
```

Me aparece que todo es correcto excepto los comentarios, porque creo que me cuenta tanto si es true como si es False entonces aparecen más comentarios de los que hay. Si alguien me podría decir como podría contar solo los booleanos que sean sí, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Antes que nada, tu función recibe un `dataframe` pero en el Paso 1 creas otro `dataframe`, es decir, estás creando un `dataframe` del `dataframe` que ya recibe tu función. Sería mejor que recibiera un diccionario y adentro crear el `dataframe` o recibir directamente el `dataframe` e ignorar el primer paso porque el formato de tus datos ya estaría en un `dataframe`. En la respuesta propuesta cambié por un diccionario los datos de entrada.

No lo explicas en tu pregunta pero parece que la columna "COMENTARIO" tiene `strings` "TRUE" y "FALSE" que no pueden ser interpretados como booleanos directamente, para convertirlos a sus respectivos booleanos podemos utilizar `map`:

```
df['COMENTARIO'] = df['COMENTARIO'].map({'TRUE': True, 'FALSE': False})
```

Ahora, como esos valores ya son booleanos en lugar de contarlos podemos sumarlos ya que `True` se interpretaría como `1` y `False` como `0`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Es mejor recibir un diccionario y crear el dataframe adentro de tu función
def calcular_estadisticas(descargas:dict)->pd.DataFrame:
    # Paso 1: cargar los datos
    df = pd.DataFrame(descargas)
    
    # TRUE y FALSE son strings por lo que hay que convertirlos a booleanos
    # Convertir TRUE a True y FALSE a False
    df['COMENTARIO'] = df['COMENTARIO'].map({'TRUE': True, 'FALSE': False})
    
    # Paso 2: filtrar los datos
    df_pagados = df[df["PAGO"] > 0]
    
    # Paso 3: calcular las estadísticas
    agg_dict = {
        "PAGO": ["count", "mean", "max", "min"],
        "ESTRELLAS": ["mean", "std"],
        # Reemplazamos count por sum
        "COMENTARIO": ["sum"]
    }
    stats = df_pagados.groupby("MODELO").agg(agg_dict)
    
    # Paso 4: crear el DataFrame resultado
    resultado = pd.DataFrame({
        "CANTIDAD": stats["PAGO"]["count"].astype(int),
        "PROMEDIO": stats["PAGO"]["mean"].round(2),
        "MAXIMO": stats["PAGO"]["max"].round(2),
        "MINIMO": stats["PAGO"]["min"].round(2),
        "ESTRELLAS": stats["ESTRELLAS"]["mean"].round(2),
        "DESV. ESTRELLAS": stats["ESTRELLAS"]["std"].fillna(0).round(2),
        # Reemplazamos count por sum
        "COMENTARIOS": stats["COMENTARIO"]["sum"].astype(int)
    }, index=stats.index)
    
    # Ordenar los resultados alfabéticamente por nombre de modelo
    resultado = resultado.sort_index()
    
    return resultado

data = {'MODELO': ['Bus urbano #27', 'Silla tipo bar', 'Piano', 'Fuente con flores', 'Bus urbano #27', 'Puesto de Yogurt', 'Playground', 'Bus urbano #27'],
        'USUARIO': ['Ted Mosby', 'Art Vandelay', 'Art Vandelay', 'Michael', 'Mark Brendanawicz', 'Michael', 'Mark Brendanawicz', 'LeCorbusier_2020'],
        'PAGO': [24.99,4.99,4.99,0,12,0,14,0],
        'ESTRELLAS': [5,3.5,3.5,5,4,5,4.5,1],
        'COMENTARIO': ['TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE']}

calcular_estadisticas(data)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
                CANTIDAD  PROMEDIO  MAXIMO  MINIMO  ESTRELLAS  \
MODELO                                                          
Bus urbano #27         2     18.49   24.99   12.00        4.5   
Piano                  1      4.99    4.99    4.99        3.5   
Playground             1     14.00   14.00   14.00        4.5   
Silla tipo bar         1      4.99    4.99    4.99        3.5   

                DESV. ESTRELLAS  COMENTARIOS  
MODELO                                        
Bus urbano #27             0.71            2  
Piano                      0.00            0  
Playground                 0.00            1  
Silla tipo bar             0.00            0
```

Comment: Ocurre un problema y creo que esta al utilizar fillna(0) para que sustituya esos valores por cero, el programa lo que debe hacer en la desviación estandar es que cuando aparezca Nan deba cambiarlo a 0.0, he probado a cambiar 0 por 0.0 pero de ninguna de las dos formas llega a ser correcto porque obtengo este error "Can not convert Na to integrer"

Comment: Buen día, no sé en qué parte estas teniendo el error pero de igual forma me parece que sería un tema que no está relacionado con la pregunta original que era obtener el resultado de los comentarios. ¿Podrías crear una nueva pregunta mostrando el código que tienes actualmente, el error y el resultado esperado?